# JavaScript Array.sort() not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

say I have an array that I want to sort, that a certain element will be first, and leave the rest the way it is.

for example [1,2,3,4] and I want the 2 to be at the beginning of the array

```
[1,2,3,4].sort((a,b)=> a == 2 ? -1 : 0)
```

in chrome the output is as expected

```
// chrome
[2,1,3,4]
```

but in Firefox the output is different and the 2 is not first

```
// firefox
[1,2,3,4]
```

Comment: You're supposed to *compare two elements*, not return whether the first of the two equals `2`.

Comment: That is no proper ordering. Depending on the implementation of the `sort` different outcomes can and will happen.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You also need to handle the cases were `b` is `2` properly:

```
 .sort((a, b) => (b === 2) - (a === 2))
```

> but in Firefox the array is not sorted

Not quite, Firefox might use a different sorting algorithm, such that the sorter is called with different arguments in a different order. The array is only sorted correctly in all different implementations if the following conditions are always true:

```
  sorter(a, a) === 0
  sorter(a, b) === - sorter(b, a)
```

---

Note that sorting is usually O(n log n) average case (though it could be better if a lot of elements are equal), whereas the problem can be solved in O(n):

```
 const withoutTwo = array.filter(it => it !== 2);
 const result =
   Array.from({ length: array.length - withoutTwo.length }).fill(2)
    .concat(withoutTwo);
```

Comment: This works because `false - false === 0` and according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort *"If compareFunction(a, b) returns 0, leave a and b unchanged with respect to each other, but sorted with respect to all different elements. Note: the ECMAScript standard only started guaranteeing this behavior in 2019, thus, older browsers may not respect this."*, right?

Comment: @luk2302 exactly. In other words although { 2 } < N \ { 2 } only defines a partial order, for two equal elements the index is taken, so we're basically sorting N², (el, index) > (el2, index2) and that should be a total order if I'm not mistaken

Comment: Your answer was right though in the way that one could skip a lot of unneccessary comparisons with a different approach, reducing complexity to O(n)

Comment: Yeah, but I was not aware of the specification and was honestly not expecting your code / any sort to work until I actually tried your snippet out with different inputs.

Comment: `sorter(a, b) === - sorter(b, a)` should probably be `sign(sorter(a, b)) === - sign(sorter(b, a))` ;)

Comment: @georg yeah, though for most practical implementations that distinction is not relevant ...

Answer (score 1):

```js
[1,2,3,4].sort((a,b)=> a == 2 ? -1 :  (b==2 ? 1 :0))
```

Comment: A small explanation about what the code does or where the OP's error was would be a great addition to otherwise code only, thus a low quality post